# Finding number of elements that are greater than their neighbors in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the number of elements in a list that are greater than both of their neighbors (excluding the first and last because they don't have two neighbors)

I was sure this was the right way to do it but I guess not. I'll be honest I don't fully understand how the input is taken as that is given to us at the start of the problem.

```py
acc = 0
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
for x in range(1, len(a) - 1):
  if(a[x] > a[x + 1] and a[x] < a[x - 1]):
    acc += 1
print(acc)
```

When given `-9 29 -100 64 26 73 -96 28 -92 11 -14 -86 -54 -67` it expects 6 but my code gives 1.

Comment: try `if a[x - 1] < a[x] and a[x] > a[x + 1]:`

Comment: @Ruzihm that worked! I feel so stupid now, thanks so much!

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic due to being caused by a typographical error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = [-9, 29, -100, 64, 26, 73, -96, 28, -92, 11, -14, -86, -54, -67]
```

**Most Pythonic**

```
sum([x > lst[i] and x > lst[i+2] for i, x in enumerate(lst[1:-1])])
```

- `sum()` over boolean for counting
- loop over the middle values
- find out which numbers by:

```
[(x, (lst[i], lst[i+2])) for i, x in enumerate(lst[1:-1]) if x > lst[i] and x > lst[i+2]]
```

Returning:

```
[(29, -9, -100),
 (64, -100, 26),
 (73, 26, -96),
 (28, -96, -92),
 (11, -92, -14),
 (-54, -86, -67)]
```

**Also possible ...**

```
sum([x > max(y) for x, y in zip(lst[1:-1], zip(lst[:-2], lst[2:]))]) ## 6
```

- with `lst[1:-1]` being all numbers with 2 neighbours
- `lst[:-2]` all pre-neighbours
- `lst[2:]` all after-neighbours
- `zip()` pairs them together into tuples
- `max()` looks for the greatest of both neighbours - if x is greater than them, it is greater than both
- the boolean expression `x > max(y)` collecting `True` and `False`
- which can be `sum()`ed up for counting.

**Check:**

You can collect which values these are by:

```
[(x, y) for x, y in zip(lst[1:-1], zip(lst[:-2], lst[2:])) if x > max(y)]

## returning:
[(29, (-9, -100)),
 (64, (-100, 26)),
 (73, (26, -96)),
 (28, (-96, -92)),
 (11, (-92, -14)),
 (-54, (-86, -67))]
```

**Remark**

With the `zip()` I was actually searching for a way of parallely loop over
pre- and after-neighbors and the middle values ...

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0] > max(x[1]), zip(lst[1:-1], zip(lst[:-2], lst[2:]))))
```

But yeah, it is more pythonic to use simple for loop and simple comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your if condition is wrong.

It should read: `if a[x] > a[x + 1] and a[x] > a[x - 1]` instead of `if a[x] > a[x + 1] and a[x] < a[x - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution

```
data = [-9, 29, -100, 64, 26, 73, -96, 28, -92, 11, -14, -86, -54, -67]
data2 = [data[i] for i in range(1, len(data)-1) if data[i-1]  < data[i] > data[i+1]]
print(data2)
```

Output:

```
[29, 64, 73, 28, 11, -54]
```

Now you can get the length of the generated array `len(data2)`. Another option
is using a function like you did, you can use `a < b < c` expressions to save some typing

```
def greater_neighbors(a):
    acc = 0
    for x in range(1, len(a) - 1):
      if(a[x + 1] < a[x] > a[x - 1]):
        acc += 1
    return acc

print(greater_neighbors(data))
```